# Gradle doesn't download jars

Tags: maven, gradle, offline-caching

I am working on a gradle project that should run on a machine without internet connection.

For that, I have created a task that takes the gradle cache and copies it into another directory, to be used as a local repository.

I have built the project in online mode and it worked.
I have ran my task to copy the cache to the local repository and it worked.
However, when trying to run `gradle build --offline` I am getting errors like this (for several different jar files):

```
Could not download commons-math3.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.4.1): No cached version available for offline mode
```

Checking both my local repository and the gradle cache, I couldn't find the relevant jar file (in this case `commons-math3-3.4.1.jar`).

I have tried using `gradle build --refresh-dependencies`, I have tried to delete the cache and then using `gradle build` - nothing, it wouldn't download the jar files, only the pom files.
I have even tried to download the jars manually and put them in the correct directories in my local repository did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Gradle cache can be transferred to another machine like this. I'm trying to create a plugin which can copy the dependencies from a configuration to a local directory for offline usage [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-dependency-export) but I've hit [this issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2809) where parent POM's and BOM's can't be accessed from the Gradle API's. I've got a failing test [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-dependency-export/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/lazan/dependency/export/MavenDependencyExportTest.groovy#L69) demonstrating the usage of the plugin and the lack of parent POM support.

One of the suggestions on the issue is to try the [IvyPot plugin](https://github.com/ysb33r/ivypot-gradle-plugin). I haven't tried this myself but it might work for what you are attempting.

Comment: That's sort of what I did (created a plugin to copy the cache into a directory within the project to be used as a local offline repository). It was less preety, but it works (I had built and ran a smaller test project offline successfully). My problem is that I don't have the mentioned jar file (and 3 others) in the gradle cache, so I cannot copy them to my offline repository, so it doesn't work.

Comment: That sounds quite hacky, the Gradle cache directory is a private implementation which you shouldn't be accessing. If jars are missing then I'm guessing you copied the cache before [`Configuration.resolve()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#resolve()) was invoked on one or more configurations

Comment: I have built the project online, copied the jars and poms, tried to build offline and got said error.

Answer (score 0):

You might have proxy enabled, add proxy details in "gradle.properties" file like below:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=your.proxy.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=XXXX
systemProp.http.proxyUser=user
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
```